# ASP.NET: How do I implement my own AssociatedControlID-like functionality?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, findcontrol

I have two user controls A and B, where B depends on the existence of A in the same page.

I'm trying to implement some functionality like this:

```
<mine:A ID="IdOfTheAControl" runat="server" />
<mine:B BelongsTo="IdOfTheAControl" runat="server" />
```

I'm able to extract `"IdOfTheAControl"` but unable to get the actual control with that ID. I tried to use `FindControl("IdOfTheAControl")` in `Page_Load` for `B` but this returns `null`, probably because the function looks for the control in `B.ascx` and not the master page where the two controls are siblings.

How do I, from a user control, get access to another user control with a given ID if the two controls are siblings in a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since user controls inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControl, they have a Page and Parent property. The Page will give you a handle to the page and Parent a handle to the control that hosts your control if there are nested controls.

try mineB.Page.FindControl("IdOfTheAControl"); //pseudo code

Comment: If anyone wants to know, I used `Parent.FindControl` and it worked fine.